# Async Loading of a TreeView

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, tornadofx

Hey I am very new to tornadofx struggeling with async loading of data for the treeview. I am loading categories from a rest endpoint, which I want to show in there.

It seems like there's no direct data binding to the children.

when using 'bindChildren' I can provide the observable list, but I have to convert them into Node's. which then would make the populate block kind of obsolete.

What's the recommended way of doing this? I cannot find anything about this.

```
// Category
interface Category<T : Category<T>> {
  val id: String
  val name: String
  val subcategories: List<T>?
}


//default category:
class DefaultCategory(override val name: String) : Category<DefaultCategory> {
  override val id: String = "default"
  override val subcategories: List<DefaultCategory>? = null
}
//ViewModel
class CategoryViewModel : ViewModel() {
  val sourceProperty = SimpleListProperty<Category<*>>()
  fun loadData() {
    // load items for treeview into 'newItems'
    sourceProperty.value = newItems
  }
}

// TreeViewFactoryMethod
private fun createTreeView(
  listProperty: SimpleListProperty<Category<*>>
): TreeView<Category<*>> {
  return treeview {
    root = TreeItem(DefaultCategory("Categories"))
    isShowRoot = false
    root.isExpanded = true
    root.children.forEach { it.isExpanded = true }
    cellFormat { text = it.name }
    populate { parent ->
      when (parent) {
        root -> listProperty.value
        else -> parent.value.subcategories
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming that on a button click I call `viewmodel.loadData()`, I would expect the TreeView to update as soon as there's some new data. (If I would've found a way to bind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never had to use `bindChildren` for TornadoFX before and your use of async isn't very relevant to what I think is your primary problem. So, admittedly, this question kind of confused me at first but I'm guessing you're just wondering why the list isn't appearing in your `TreeView`? I've made a test example with changes to make it work.

```
// Category
interface Category<T : Category<T>> {
    val id: String
    val name: String
    val subcategories: List<T>?
}

//default category:
class DefaultCategory(override val name: String) : Category<DefaultCategory> {
    override val id: String = "default"
    override val subcategories: List<DefaultCategory>? = null
}
//Just a dummy category
class ChildCategory(override val name: String) : Category<ChildCategory> {
    override val id = name
    override val subcategories: List<ChildCategory>? = null
}

//ViewModel
class CategoryViewModel : ViewModel() {
    //filled with dummy data
    val sourceProperty = SimpleListProperty<Category<*>>(listOf(
            ChildCategory("Categorya"),
            ChildCategory("Categoryb"),
            ChildCategory("Categoryc"),
            ChildCategory("Categoryd")
    ).asObservable())

    fun loadData() {
        sourceProperty.asyncItems {
            //items grabbed somehow
            listOf(
                    ChildCategory("Category1"),
                    ChildCategory("Category2"),
                    ChildCategory("Category3"),
                    ChildCategory("Category4")
            ).asObservable()
        }
    }
}


class TestView : View() {
    val model: CategoryViewModel by inject()

    override val root = vbox(10) {
        button("Refresh Items").action {
            model.loadData()
        }
        add(createTreeView(model.sourceProperty))
    }

    // TreeViewFactoryMethod
    private fun createTreeView(
            listProperty: SimpleListProperty<Category<*>>
    ): TreeView<Category<*>> {
        return treeview {
            root = TreeItem(DefaultCategory("Categories"))
            isShowRoot = false
            root.isExpanded = true
            root.children.forEach { it.isExpanded = true }
            cellFormat { text = it.name }
            populate { parent ->
                when (parent) {
                    root -> listProperty
                    else -> parent.value.subcategories
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 important distinctions that are important.

**1.** The more relevant distinction is that inside the populate block, `root -> listProperty` is used instead of `root.listProperty.value`. This will make your list appear. The reason is that a `SimpleListProperty` is not a list, it *holds* a list. So, yes, passing in a plain list is perfectly valid (like how you passed in the *value* of the list property). But now that means the tree view isn't listening to your property, just the list you passed in. With that in mind, I would be considerate over the categories' subcategory lists are implemented as well.

**2.** Secondly, notice the use of `asyncItems` in the `ViewModel`. This will perform whatever task asynchronously, then set the items to list on success. You can even add `fail` or `cancel` blocks to it. I'd recommend using this, as long/intensive operations aren't supposed to be performed on the UI thread.

Comment: `sourceProperty.asyncItems` was the missing link. thank you